# How to update object with a list of objects inside JDO

Tags: java, jdo, objectdb

I'm trying to update an object called "Alumno", this is the class:

```
public class Alumno extends Persona {

private Alumno alumno;


private List<String> telefonos;


private Direccion direccion;


private List<Asignatura> asignaturas;
```

And this is the class "Asignatura":

```
public class Asignatura {

private String alias;


private String nombre;


private Long curso;


private Profesor profesor;


private List<Alumno> alumnos;
```

I get that the error is because there is already an Asignatura called "AED", but how can I "merge" the list into the db? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of code that you posted doesn't show where and how you create the `Asignatura` objects.

In order to merge existing database objects make sure that first you retrieve them in the same PersistenceManager (and if possible in the same transaction) and then you connect these retrieved objects to other objects that you want to update.

Comment: Well I didn't know how to do that so what I did was removing the objects before inserting them. I know it's not the best way but it works. Thanks for the help!